# How to join two dataframes on football matches and footall player stats making n columns for each of the players?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on building a substantial dataset for football games predictions, and I have the following dataframes, player_stats:

```
players_stats : ['player_name', 'Age', 'overall_rating', 'preferred_foot',
       'attacking_work_rate', 'defensive_work_rate', 'acceleration',
       'ball_control', 'reactions', 'stamina', 'strength', 'aggression']

 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   player_name          11060 non-null  object 
 1   player_fifa_api_id   11060 non-null  int64  
 2   player_api_id        11060 non-null  int64  
 3   id                   11060 non-null  int64  
 4   Age                  11060 non-null  int64  
 5   overall_rating       11021 non-null  float64
 6   preferred_foot       11021 non-null  object 
 7   attacking_work_rate  10897 non-null  object 
 8   defensive_work_rate  11021 non-null  object 
 9   acceleration         11021 non-null  float64
 10  ball_control         11021 non-null  float64
 11  reactions            11021 non-null  float64
 12  stamina              11021 non-null  float64
 13  strength             11021 non-null  float64
 14  aggression           11021 non-null  float64
```

And test_matches_df:

```
test_matches_df: ['country', 'league_x', 'season', 'date', 'home_team_api_id',
       'home_team', 'away_team_api_id', 'away_team', 'home_goal', 'away_goal',
       'shoton', 'shotoff', 'foulcommit', 'card', 'cross', 'corner',
       'possession', 'result', 'home_player_1', 'home_player_2',
       'home_player_3', 'home_player_4', 'home_player_5', 'home_player_6',
       'home_player_7', 'home_player_8', 'home_player_9', 'home_player_10',
       'home_player_11', 'away_player_1', 'away_player_2', 'away_player_3',
       'away_player_4', 'away_player_5', 'away_player_6', 'away_player_7',
       'away_player_8', 'away_player_9', 'away_player_10', 'away_player_11',
       'B365H', 'B365D', 'BWH', 'IWH', 'LBH', 'Team', 'Country', 'league_y',
       'id', 'team_fifa_api_id', 'team_api_id', 'defencePressure',
       'defenceAggression', 'buildUpPlaySpeed', 'buildUpPlayPassing']

 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------              --------------  -----  
 0   country             3040 non-null   object 
 1   league_x            3040 non-null   object 
 2   season              3040 non-null   object 
 3   date                3040 non-null   object 
 4   home_team_api_id    3040 non-null   int64  
 5   home_team           3040 non-null   object 
 6   away_team_api_id    3040 non-null   int64  
 7   away_team           3040 non-null   object 
 8   home_goal           3040 non-null   int64  
 9   away_goal           3040 non-null   int64  
 10  shoton              3040 non-null   object 
 11  shotoff             3040 non-null   object 
 12  foulcommit          3040 non-null   object 
 13  card                3040 non-null   object 
 14  cross               3040 non-null   object 
 15  corner              3040 non-null   object 
 16  possession          3040 non-null   object 
 17  result              3040 non-null   int64  
 18  home_player_1       3040 non-null   object 
 19  home_player_2       3040 non-null   object 
 20  home_player_3       3040 non-null   object 
 21  home_player_4       3040 non-null   object 
 22  home_player_5       3040 non-null   object 
 23  home_player_6       3040 non-null   object 
 24  home_player_7       3040 non-null   object 
 25  home_player_8       3040 non-null   object 
 26  home_player_9       3040 non-null   object 
 27  home_player_10      3040 non-null   object 
 28  home_player_11      3040 non-null   object 
 29  away_player_1       3040 non-null   object 
 30  away_player_2       3040 non-null   object 
 31  away_player_3       3040 non-null   object 
 32  away_player_4       3040 non-null   object 
 33  away_player_5       3040 non-null   object 
 34  away_player_6       3040 non-null   object 
 35  away_player_7       3040 non-null   object 
 36  away_player_8       3040 non-null   object 
 37  away_player_9       3040 non-null   object 
 38  away_player_10      3040 non-null   object 
 39  away_player_11      3040 non-null   object 
 40  B365H               3040 non-null   float64
 41  B365D               3040 non-null   float64
 42  BWH                 3039 non-null   float64
 43  IWH                 3038 non-null   float64
 44  LBH                 3039 non-null   float64
 45  Team                3040 non-null   object 
 46  Country             3040 non-null   object 
 47  league_y            3040 non-null   object 
 48  id                  3040 non-null   int64  
 49  team_fifa_api_id    3040 non-null   int64  
 50  team_api_id         3040 non-null   int64  
 51  defencePressure     3040 non-null   int64  
 52  defenceAggression   3040 non-null   int64  
 53  buildUpPlaySpeed    3040 non-null   int64  
 54  buildUpPlayPassing  3040 non-null   int64
```

How can I join these two so that for each of those players (home_player_1, home_player_2) etc I get their correspective values in the player_stats df? Aka for each home and away player,  there will be columns like home_player_1.acceleration, home_player_1.strength and so on

| test_matches_df.home_player_1 | players_stats.home_player_1_strength | test_matches_df.home_player_2 | players_stats.home_player_2_strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 78 | 222222 | 94 |

This is what I tried so far:

```
player_columns = ['home_player_1', 'home_player_2', 'home_player_3', 'home_player_4', 'home_player_5', 'home_player_6',
                  'home_player_7', 'home_player_8', 'home_player_9', 'home_player_10', 'home_player_11',
                  'away_player_1', 'away_player_2', 'away_player_3', 'away_player_4', 'away_player_5', 'away_player_6',
                  'away_player_7', 'away_player_8', 'away_player_9', 'away_player_10', 'away_player_11']

test_matches_df[player_columns] = test_matches_df[player_columns].astype(str)

joined_dfs = {}

for player_col in player_columns:
    player_number = player_col.split('_')[-1]
    alias = f'{player_col}_stats'
    [alias] = pd.merge(test_matches_df,
                                 players_stats.rename(columns={'player_name': f'player_{player_number}'}),
                                 left_on=[player_col],
                                 right_on=[f'player_{player_number}'],
                                 how='left')

result_df = pd.concat(list(joined_dfs.values()), axis=1)
result_df = result_df.loc[:, ~result_df.columns.duplicated()]
result_df = result_df.drop(player_columns, axis=1)
print(result_df.head())
```

The problem with the code above, is that while it performs without error, the resulting dataframes are all empty.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Also add what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Thank you @mandy8055, you're right I added those sections.

Comment: I can see in your code you're trying to join the `df's` based on `player_number` as key. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I think this isn't a good idea. I have just modified my SQL query to now obtain the ids as well. The problem is that I have no idea which ID is the one used in test_matches_df. 

You can check the edits. Do you want to see the SQL queries I run to get those dataframes as well?

Comment: i think you can make us get reproduciblilty. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with left join and then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
players_stats = pd.DataFrame({'player_name':['p1','p2','p3','p4'],
                              'stamina':[1,2,6,8],
                              'strength':[10,72,86,38]})

test_matches_df = pd.DataFrame({'home_player_1':['p1','p2'],
                                'home_player_2':['p3','p4']})

player_columns = ['home_player_1', 'home_player_2']
    
out = (test_matches_df[player_columns]
                .reset_index()
                .melt('index',value_name='player_name')
                .merge(players_stats, on='player_name', how='left')
                .pivot(index='index', columns='variable')
                .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
                )
out.columns = [f'{b}.{a}' for a, b in out.columns]
print (out)
      home_player_1.player_name  home_player_1.stamina  \
index                                                    
0                            p1                      1   
1                            p2                      2   

       home_player_1.strength home_player_2.player_name  \
index                                                     
0                          10                        p3   
1                          72                        p4   

       home_player_2.stamina  home_player_2.strength  
index                                                 
0                          6                      86  
1                          8                      38
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as player_name is classified as 'object'. Also, I don't have a corresponding 'player_name' in the other dataframe, so I need to change column. 

In the edits I added a new dataframe I obtained with the SQL queries that gives me IDs as well, not just player names

Comment: @spool - Unfortunately not understand. I add my sample data for working solution. Can you explain more `Also, I don't have a corresponding 'player_name' in the other dataframe, so I need to change column.`

Comment: Thanks for this, the thing is `test_matches_df` is the dataframe containing all columns for each players, so only `players_stats` has the IDs, but I don't have the names in the `test_matches_df`, I only have the IDs. So I need those to merge on, if it makes sense.

Comment: @spool - So instead `['p1','p2','p3','p4']` should be `[1,2]` because `home_player_1, home_player_2` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, although they are classified as floats not ints.

Comment: @spool - But it means there are match by column names, not by values? So each column has same values?